# How to code a Discord Bot to make scheduled announcements

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, setinterval, scheduler

I am extremely new to coding and I'm trying to figure out codes for two things.

1. Recurring announcements, like a "hello" everyday at the same time
2. Scheduled announcements for specific times/days etc.

I'm using Autocode which I believe uses JavaScript for its coding.

This is the code I was attempting to use for interval messages:

```
const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});

var checkminutes = 10, checkthe_interval = checkminutes * 60 * 1000; //This checks every 10 minutes, change 10 to whatever minute you'd like
setInterval(function() {
  message.channel.send("hello world");
    //Or anything else
}, checkthe_interval);
```

And then this is the code I was trying to use for scheduled tasks:

```
const lib = require('lib')({token: process.env.STDLIB_SECRET_TOKEN});

const cron = require('cron');

const channel = require ('873698467262898236');
const job = new cron.CronJob('0 0 8 * * *', () => {
  channel.send("It's 8:00 am.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with cron:

```
let NAME = new cron.CronJob('00 00 08 * * *', () => {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('ID_OF_SERVER');
  const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('ID_OF_CHANNEL');
  channel.send('Your message')
});
NAME.start();
```

You also have to specifie timezone, or just figue out deafult and change time

Comment: It doesn't seem to be triggering a response in my server, I'm using the default time to make it easier

Comment: do you have any errors in console? I also figured out that default timezone for cron is UTC+0 so you just have to convert it to your timezone (if your timezone is UTC+2 then you have to change hour 8 to 6). Maybe you pasted wrong IDs, i'm running bot on replit server with cron installed and it works